# How should I treat my garage wall?

Tags: walls, garage, brick

I want to turn my garage into a bit of a woodworking shop (I am an amateur at best) so I want to put things on the wall such as tools and other things that must be stored there.

My garage has very rough bricks that i've never seen before (Pictured). Do I need to clad these to get a good fastening or can I drill straight into the wall?

If I do need/decide to clad the wall, how should I do it? Are there damp issues to consider?

Edit with some background: The garage is completely detached so on the other side of the wall is fresh air. The garage wall may be multiple bricks thick, i'm not sure. The garage is completely unheated currently so it's literally just a brick box. I live in the northern UK so could experience temperatures between something like -10 and 30 celsius.

[image: My Wall]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What's behind your wall? What's your climate? Is the garage heated or cooled?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I've updated the question with more info.